# how can I enable mint desktop sharing before anyone has logged in?

Tags: linux-mint, vnc

Currently I can use vncviewr to access a Mint-18 desktop after a user has logged in.

How can I set up the mint-18 box such that desktop sharing is available even when no one has logged into the machine.

Comment: have you thought about [x2go](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php) (if you are using MATE or Xfce)?

Comment: @DJCrashdummy thanks but I'm using Cinnamon...which of the machines should be running MATE the host or the client or both?

Comment: well... the clients can even run Windows or Mac OS X. -- the server can principally also run Cinnamon or KDE, but when you want to work in a Cinnamon-/KDE-session (or any other DE with graphic acceleration) via x2go it won't work. you just need a (additional) DE without graphic acceleration if you want to use a whole DE in x2go.

Comment: but keep in mind x2go is **not** really a desktop **sharing** application (although a additional package is available), it is more a "remote login" application!